# usort and compare function with arguments PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare, usort

I have question
My code works but i dont understand what is $x[1] and $y[1] in function
I tryed $x[0], $x[1], $x[2], $y[0], $y[1], $y[2] and dont get the logical output ? Where i am wrong to understand ? Please if someone can help me ?

```
<?php
$products = array( array('TIR', 'Tires', 100),
                   array('OIL', 'Oil', 10),
                   array ('SPK', 'Spark Plugs', 4));

//print_r ($products); echo '<br />';
                 
function compare($x, $y) {
    if ($x[1] == $y[1]) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($x[1]<$y[1]) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

usort ($products, 'compare');

echo compare('Tires', 'Tires' );
echo compare('Oil', 'Spark Plugs' );
echo compare('Spark Plugs', 'Oil' );
echo compare('Tires', 'Tires');
echo '<br />';
```

Output is for this code for echo 1, 2, 3, 4:

```
0
-1
1
0
```

Comment: $x and $y are two of the elements of your array that you are trying to sort, that get passed into your comparison function. So `$x[0]` is the first element of one of those sub-arrays, `$x[1]` is the second, etc.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is what if i put $x[2] and $y[2], i get right output, but if i put $x[1] and $y[1] i cant understaund output ? where i am wrong to understand the code ?

Comment: With [2] you would be sorting by the 100, 10 and 4 values, and with [1] you are sorting by `Tires`, `Oil` and `Spark Plugs` instead.

Comment: I understand that, but function compare dont get the logical output when i put strings to compare ? Where i am wrong to understand ?

Comment: Your `echo compare('Tires', 'Tires' );` etc. below the actual `usort` call, make little sense. That does something completely different, here you would be comparing the second or third _letter_ of the word `Tires`. These statements make no sense whatsoever here. If you want to see what your sorted array looks like - then var_dump it.

Comment: i understand and that, but when i am try to compare $x[0] TIR and $y[0] i get unlogical output, even the first letter is TIR, OIL ... Or i mispelled somethingf to understand better ?

Comment: Your `compare` function here is written in a way, that calling it really only makes any sense with _arrays_ as parameters for $x and $y. Using that same function, and calling it like this, `compare('Oil', 'Spark Plugs' )` makes very little sense here to begin with.

Comment: make no or little sense, i get wrong or unlogical output .. Please if you can explain me what is exactly if i put $x[0] and $y[0] ... what elements are exactly that variables with [0] ?

Comment: Imagine the strings as arrays of characters. So if you have `Tires` as your string, then `$x[0]` is `T`˙, `$x[1]` is `i` and so on. Same goes for `$y`. The output you show in your question is perfectly consistent with the code. Why did you think it was wrong?

Comment: What $x[0] is, depends on what you are calling your function with in the first place. When `usort` calls your function, it passes in one of the elements of your array - so $x could f.e. be `array('TIR', 'Tires', 100)`, then $x[0] would of course refer to the `TIR` element of that array. When _you_ call `compare('Oil', 'Spark Plugs' )`, that is something completely different to begin with - you are not passing in arrays for the parameters here, but simple strings. So $x is `Oil` now, and accessing the first character of that using [0], gets you the `O`.

Comment: _“i get wrong or unlogical output”_ - you are comparing apples and oranges here; the way `usort` calls your comparison function, and the way you call it, are fundamentally different. For what you are doing there, the output _is_ “logical” - but as a way of verifying whether your sorting worked, or whether your comparison function is even correct for that purpose, it is _not_ suitable.

Comment: Why i canot use usort function ? If i have good understanding of your talk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `compare($x, $y)` function, you are passing the strings as the parameters. These string are treated as arrays with 0-based indexing.

So, when `echo compare('Tires', 'Tires' );` is executed, these two strings are passed and according to compare function, the character at index 1(indexing starts at 0) i.e. 2nd character is compared.

---

So, for this ```echo compare('Tires', 'Tires' );```, the compared characters are 'i' and 'i' which are equal and hence 0 is returned.

So, for this `echo compare('Oil', 'Spark Plugs' );`, the compared characters are 'i' and 'p'. 'i' is less than p and hence -1 is returned. To decide which character is lower than the other, lookup ASCII codes.

And so on for other function calls. Let me know, if you still have any doubt.

This I have explained for just the independent `echo compare('Oil', 'Spark Plugs' );` line not for `usort` function.

**UPDATE For the usort function**
Let me first explain the way a comparator functions works. Whenever two parameters are passed to the compare function, it returns true or false and this is used to determine whether you need to swap those values or not.
In the earlier case, `echo compare('Tirez', 'Tires' );` 
`$x = Tires`, and 
`$y = Tirez`
You compare `$x[1]` and `$y[1]`, particularly the character at index 1. But what if in the case of these strings, you just do `$x < &y`, the strings are compared automatically character-by-character according to ASCII codes for English alphabets and the result is returned on the first position, the characters do not match.
i.e. if you want to compare if one string is **lexicographically** smaller than the other string then you can use the below comparator function.

```
function compare($x, $y) {
    if ($x == $y) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($x < $y) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The output will be `1`, since while comparing character-by-character `'z' > 's'`.

---

So, when a complete array is passed to compare function, the first two elements are passed. Here the array `$products` is a 2D array (an array of arrays), so the first two arrays are passed
i.e. `$x = array('TIR', 'Tires', 100)`, and 
      `$y = array('OIL', 'Oil', 10)`
So, it depends on your requirement. For example, if you want to sort by index 0 of any array of `$products` i.e. 'TIR', 'OIL', 'SPK' then change the comparator function to `$x[0]` and `$y[0]`.
I hope you are able to understand now :).

Comment: $x and $y are the variables i define in compare function and that i understand but not understand if i try to compare strings, What if i try to compare $x[0] and $y[0] like first elements in array (TIR, OIL etc.) ? If T and O like first sting elements in string why my output is wrong ? Thanks for the answer but stil i have doubt ? The same output is in case i //coment usort fnc

Comment: @MilutinGavrilovic Can you tell me your desired output?

Comment: Now for $x[0], and $y[0]  and for $x[1] and $y[1]give me this output for 4 echos 0,-1,1,0 and i cant understand how gives me the same output, because TIR and Tires, OIL and Oil, Spark Plugs are the same but not letter case. My question is: What is exactly i check > TIR or Tires is the $x[0] are TIR(T) or $x[1] is Tires(i) ... can you understand me now ?

Comment: What if i want to compare this: echo compare ('TIR', 'SPK'); Is this the $x[0] and $y[0] or i misspelit something ?

Comment: What if i want to compare this: echo compare ('TIR', 'SPK'); Is this the $x[0] and $y[0] or i misspelit something ? And that output for this example is not clear in my mind ... In this case: Is the $x[0] the TIR or  just T ... I cant understand what i compare and i dont understand which is in the two cases TIR and Tires (Thats parameters - i think)... But why i cant compare for example TIR and SPK - [0] - thats T and S if i have good thinking ? What is [0] TIR or just T from first row ? Am i clear now or ?

Comment: For `echo compare ('TIR', 'SPK');`, `$x = 'TIR'` and `$x[0] = 'T'`, `$y = 'SPK'` and `$y[0] = 'S`

Comment: Thanks man, now is much clearly in my mind :)

Comment: And now output for 'TIR' and 'SPK' is 1, because T < S in Aphabetical :) ? Am i right ?

Comment: What did you use in compare function? Also, S < T. As, A B C D E F .........O P Q R S T.....Z

Comment: In my compare function i use values to check which var is bigger if is string, or which value is bigger for integer .. If i get the point of your question ?